# Still SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null after read all of inputstream

Tags: java, android, sockets, image-processing, network-programming

I am trying to sent a screenshot from desktop to android, and display on android. As I know returned null maybe cause I did not inputStream.read() read all of inputstream, therefore I  made a while loop to read all of them then to display. The desktop also sent the size of byte array, in order to let android set the size of byte array, here is the code:

```
public class connection extends AsyncTask {
    private byte[] data;

    public void setByteSize(int size) {
        data = new byte[size];

    }

    public byte[] getByteSize() {
        return data;

    }

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object... arg0) {

        try {
            clientSocket = new Socket("134.129.125.126", 8080);
            System.out.println("client connect to server");
            input = clientSocket.getInputStream();
            System.out.println("getinputstream");
        } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        while (true) {
            int totalBytesRead = 0;
            int chunkSize = 0;
            int tempRead = 0;
            String msg = null;
            // byte[] data = null;

            byte[] tempByte = new byte[1024 * 1024 * 4];
            try {
                // read from the inputstream
                tempRead = input.read(tempByte);
                // tempbyte has x+4 byte

                System.out.println("Fist time read:" + tempRead);
                // convert x+4 byte into String

                String message = new String(tempByte, 0, tempRead);
                msg = message.substring(0, 4);
                // cut the header into imageMsg
                String imageMsg = new String(tempByte, 4, tempRead - 4);
                // convert string into byte
                System.out.println("message head:" + msg);
                byteSize = Integer.parseInt(msg);
                System.out.println("ByteSize:" + byteSize);
                data = imageMsg.getBytes();
                setByteSize(byteSize);

                totalBytesRead = tempRead - 4;
                System.out.println("total Byte Read=" + totalBytesRead);

            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            // get string for the size of image

            try {
                int tmp = 0;

                while (chunkSize > -1) {
                    System.out.println("data length:"
                            + getByteSize().length);
                    chunkSize = input.read(getByteSize(), totalBytesRead,
                            getByteSize().length - totalBytesRead);
                    System.out.println("chunkSize is " + chunkSize);
                    System.out.println("iteration id = " + tmp);
                    tmp++;
                    totalBytesRead += chunkSize;
                    // System.out.println("Total byte read "
                    // + totalBytesRead);
                    if (totalBytesRead == getByteSize().length) {
                        break;

                    }
                }

                System.out.println("Complete reading - total read = "
                        + totalBytesRead);
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }

            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(getByteSize(), 0,
                    getByteSize().length);

            System.out.println("deco");

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                    image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    System.out.println("setImage at less than 500");

                }
            });
        }

    }

}
```

This is my decode result, I think I already read all of them, but it still do not allow me return a image

```
10-21 23:25:15.203: I/System.out(7222): Fist time read:1452
10-21 23:25:15.203: I/System.out(7222): message head:3359
10-21 23:25:15.203: I/System.out(7222): ByteSize:3359
10-21 23:25:15.203: I/System.out(7222): total Byte Read=1448
10-21 23:25:15.203: I/System.out(7222): data length:3359
10-21 23:25:15.203: I/System.out(7222): chunkSize is 1911
10-21 23:25:15.203: I/System.out(7222): iteration id = 0
10-21 23:25:15.213: I/System.out(7222): Complete reading - total read = 3359
10-21 23:25:15.213: D/skia(7222): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figure it out. The reason why is because I use setByteSize(int size) and this method will create a new byte[], which cause it turn to null.